# marginal effect of dummy variable in tobit model

Tags: r, categorical-data, sas, marginal-effect

I have a tobit regression model in hand and I want to calculate the marginal effects at means for the dummy variables in the reg equation. There are two dummy variables in the regression equation and three continuous variables. For SAS, this link has some information for the marginal effects for a tobit model : 
(http://support.sas.com/rnd/app/examples/ets/margeff/). 
However this tells me how to compute the marginal effects for continuous variables and not for a dummy variable. Could someone please help on how to do this?

Edit: So this is what I have done following the SAS link. Note that f and g are dummy variables which takes the value of 1 or 0.

proc qlim data=tobit1; 
model a = b c d f g; 
endogenous a~censored(lb=0 ub=1); 
run;

Here I input the means of the variables. Note that for the marginal effect of dummy variable g, I cannot set the value of f to its mean value as it is a dummy variable and set it at 0.

data tobit2; 
input b c d e f g a; 
datalines; 
0.48 0.34 5.59 5.57 0 1 . 
0.48 0.34 5.59 5.57 0 0 . 
run;

data tobit; 
set tobit1 tobit2; 
run;

proc qlim data=tobit noprint; 
model a = b c d f g; 
endogenous a~censored(lb=0 ub=1); 
output out = tob2 marginal; 
run; 
proc print data = man2;run;

After inputting the extra values and running the tobit regression, I get the marginal values for g 'Meff_g' for the last two added observations. In order to get the marginal effect of g at means I use: 
Meff_g(at g =1) - Meff_g(at g=0) i.e. substracting the Meff_g for the last two observations. Is this correct?

I am open to solutions using R too.